# React useState does not seem to work with object

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

this should be basic but for the love of me I can't figure out why it is not working.

So I am defining const state like this:

```
const [panels, setPanels] = useState(null);
```

then I am running an axios call to API. Doing `console.log(response.data)` give me an object similar to this:

```
{
  products: {
    basic: {...},
    intermediate: {...},
    advanced: {...}
  },
  services: {
    one_off: {...},
    weekly: {...},
    monthly: {...}
  }
}
```

When I do `setPanels(response.data)`, followed by `console.log(panels)` I expect the result similar as bove, but instead I get *null*

I also tried defining it like this:

```
const [panels, setPanels] = useState({});
```

on in axios result this:

```
let prods = response.data;
setPanels({...panels, prods});
```

but then in console I get this:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: `useState` is asynchronous - that is the reason why you cannot see your console.log.
Have you tried actually using the result in the component?

Answer (score 0):

As @Konstantin sad in comments, useState is asynchronous and panel value will be updated on some of next renders, not rigth away when you used setPanels.

As sad in docs:

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
>   state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.
>
> During subsequent re-renders, the first value returned by useState
>   will always be the most recent state after applying updates.